# Interaction smart contract

Tags: smartcontracts

I am approaching blockchain and smart contracts for the first time and I have trouble understanding some concepts.
I have to design a decision making architecture based on smart contracts. I have to manage hotel reservations based on the weather. The weather information is provided by the oracle. After the oracle has collected the weather data what happens? Is there an oracle smart contract that communicates with my smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Ethereum, the easiest way is to call the oracle some view-method from your smart contract and get the required data. An example is shown below.

```
 pragma solidity >=0.5.8 <0.6.0;
    
    contract Booking
    {
    
        Weather  WeatherAddr ;


       constructor() public
       {
       }
    
       function AnyFunction(bytes32  place_) public
       {
          int256  Conditions ;
          int256  Temperature ;

    
            (Conditions, Temperature)=WeatherAddr.GetWeather(place_) ;

//     ...
    
       }
    
    }
    
    contract Weather
    {

      struct PlaceWeather
      {
          int256  Temperature ;
          int256  Conditions ;
      }

    mapping (bytes32 => PlaceWeather) Places ;

    
       constructor() public
       {
       }


       function GetWeather(bytes32 place_) public view returns (int256, int256  retVal)
       {
          return(Places[place_].Conditions, Places[place_].Temperature) ;
       }
    
    }
```

Comment: how does the Weather contract retrieve the weather data from the external source?

Comment: The easiest way is to load the data as an array. This option is fine for private networks.


A more complex but flexible option is also possible. In this case, the Weather contract does not contain data, and when the GetWeather method is called, it emit an event containing the call address (i.e. Booking address) and the requested location code. The Oracle node catches the event and transactionally calls the Booking callback method, passing it weather information. In callback method, Booking restore the context of the original request and process it in accordance with the received weather.

Comment: In this way GetWeather must by specified as "payeble" and Booking send with it a certain value consisting of the service fee and gas costs for the reverse transaction.
In this case, the contract Weather must have a special method for withdrawing value to the Oracle account.

Comment: Described this in the second answer. Good luck with your project in the new year!

Answer (score 1):

Here I will schematically describe a variant with the transmission of an event to a oracle. The corresponding smart contracts are listed at the end.
The sequence of actions is as follows:

1. Deploy the contract **Weather** on the network and get its address.This must be done from the account owned by the Oracle node.
2. Enter the address of the contract **Weather** from (1) into the original text of the **Booking** contract into the **WeatherAddr** variable, compile **Booking** and deploy it to the network
3. When calling the method **BookRequest** of the contract **Booking** the following is executed:

- saving the context of the request in the **Requests** mapping
- calling the method **GetWeather** of the contract **Weather** with the transfer of the request ID and the location code, as well as the funds received from the transaction

4. Simultaneously with (3), when the **GetWeather** method of the **Weather** contract is executed, the **RequestWeather** event is initiated, in which send the request data and the address of the requesting contract **Booking**
5. The Oracle node captures the **RequestWeather** event. For this, the **eth_getLogs** or **eth_getFilterLogs** RPC API methods (or their analogs from the web3 interface) can be used. To avoid forks, I use eth_getLogs 5-6 blocks behind the last block.
6. The Oracle node extracts **location** data from the event data and determines the required weather information.
7. The Oracle node forms a transaction to the **Booking** contract address passed in the event data by calling the **CallBack** method and passing the request ID and weather data there.
8. When executing the **CallBack** method of the **Booking** contract, the following is performed:

- restoration of the request context by its identifier from the **Requests** mapping
- processing of the request in accordance with the received weather data

9. Periodically, the Oracle node forms a transaction for the **Weather** contract by calling the **SendMoneyOwner** method to transfer funds received from **Booking** contracts to its own account.

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.8 <0.6.0;
    
    contract Booking
    {

             Weather  WeatherAddr=0x00 ;  // Address of contract Weather

      struct Request
      {
          bytes32  Location ;
          bytes32  Attr1 ;
           int256  Attr2 ;
      }

    mapping (bytes32 => Request) Requests ;

       constructor() public
       {
       }
    
       function BookRequest(bytes32  id_, bytes32  location_, bytes32  attr1, int256  attr2) public payable
       {
           bool  result ;

            Requests[id_]=Request({ Location: location_, 
                                       Attr1: attr1,
                                       Attr2: attr2     }) ;

            (result,)=address(WeatherAddr).call.gas(0x300000).value(msg.value)(abi.encodeWithSignature("GetWetaher(bytes32,bytes32)", id_, location_)) ;
          if(result==false)  require(false) ;
       }

       function CallBack(bytes32  id_, int256  tempirature_) public
       {
//          1. Restore request context from Requests[id_]
//          2. Process request for booking
       }
    
    }
    
    contract Weather
    {

        address  Owner ; 
        uint256  Value ;

         event RequestWeather(address booking, bytes32 id, bytes32 location) ;

       constructor() public
       {
           Owner=tx.origin ;
       }


       function GetWeather(bytes32  id_, bytes32  location_) public payable 
       {
           Value+=msg.value ;

          emit RequestWeather(msg.sender, id_, location_) ;
       }
    
       function SendMoneyOwner() public
       {
           bool  result ;
               
            (result,)=Owner.call.gas(0x30000).value(Value)("") ;
          if(result==false)  require(false) ;

           Value=0 ;
       }
    
    }
```

Comment: I have a doubt. Is the booking contract unique or do I have a contract for each individual customer? since every request has an id I thought there was only one booking contract. Is it correct? In a real case who is the owner of the booking contract?

Comment: How to identify booking requests, contracts and their owners is the inner workings of your project. I just showed some possible mechanisms for organizing interaction with the Weather Oracle.To identify the request, you can, for example, use the standard GUID (without delimiters, it just has a size of 32 bytes), and to identify the owner, save the account of the sender of the transaction in the context of the request.

Comment: ok, last question. When BookRequest executes this line of code (result,) = address (WeatherAddr) .call.gas (0x300000) .value (msg.value) (abi.encodeWithSignature ("GetWetaher (bytes32, bytes32)", id_, location_)); what does result contain at the end? callback contains the final result (refund)? Is it correct?

Comment: No. With this call, an event is generated, which should be captured by the Oracle node (step 5). After that, the Oracle node MUST send a transaction with weather data to the CallBack method of the Booking contract. At this moment, the final data processing is performed in the CallBuck method. There will be some time gap between the GetWeather call and CallBuck, determined by the processing of the weather request by the Oracle node.

Comment: yes but what does the variable result contain at the end?
  (result,) = address (WeatherAddr) .call.gas (0x300000) .value (msg.value) (abi.encodeWithSignature ("GetWetaher (bytes32, bytes32)", id_, location_));

Comment: result=true, if transaction execute successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, typically there would be an oracle smart contract that communicates with your smart contract to provide the weather information. Oracles are third-party services that provide external data to smart contracts on the blockchain, and they are often used to trigger smart contract actions based on real-world events.

In your case, the oracle would collect weather data and send it to the oracle smart contract. The oracle smart contract would then take the weather data, process it, and send it to your smart contract. Your smart contract would then use the weather data to make a decision on hotel reservations based on your decision making architecture.

The communication between the oracle smart contract and your smart contract would typically be done through a function call or an event. Your smart contract would define a function or event that the oracle smart contract can call to provide the weather data. The oracle smart contract would then call this function or emit this event to provide the weather data to your smart contract.

It's important to note that the oracle smart contract and the oracle service itself must be trusted to provide accurate and timely data. Therefore, it's essential to thoroughly vet the oracle service and the oracle smart contract to ensure that they are secure and reliable before integrating them into your decision making architecture.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Note: "oracle" in this context is not to be confused with [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database) (completely different). Thus *not* weakening the [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) suspicion.

Comment: Strengthening it is the completely different writing style in the other [two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17107271/cryptowarrier?tab=answers) and [the (single) question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17107271/cryptowarrier?tab=questions). This is also a common pattern in regular plagiarism. Don't do it, please.